# How can I change thumbnails in Opera's speed dial?

Tags: browser, thumbnails, opera, opera-blink

I have tried to find an answer to this question, but have been unsuccessful. 
However, I did find a [website](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/211523-opera-change-speed-dial-thumbnail-images.html) that explains step-by-step how to do it for an older version of Opera.

**How can you change the speed dial thumbnails for Opera 22.0, or the latest version of Opera currently?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to http://www.symbaloo.com and create your own set of thumbnails.
2. Install an [Opera extension](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/) called "Custom Home Page" or "Homepage in New Tab" or "New Start Page Pro", and copy the address of your Symbaloo mix into the extension.
3. Start enjoying your new customizable Opera speed dial.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the given site, then press Ctrl+Shift+C or left click and inspect element.
Left click on the code, edit as html.
Press Ctrl+A to select everything, delete the code and replace it with this:

```
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
</style></head><body>

<img src="INSERT IMG URL">

</body></html>
```

Paste the link of the desired image inside the " ". (You can upload the image to Imgur or any image hosting site, copy it's link and paste it here.)
Exit the html view mode.
Click the hearth icon to save the site to your speed dials, and scroll between the images until you find the one you uploaded.

Works in Opera GX as well.

Comment: I'll keep it short, this is a seriously helpful answer. Most other places suggest editing the raw Bookmarks file (JSON) and then restarting the browser for every thumbnail. This is so much better! (Although this really should just be supported natively or via plugin.)

Comment: It really is a very imaginative solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can configure which thumbnail your speed dials and bookmarks use via the heart menu.

Comment: From the website of the Speed Dial you wish to change, click on the heart that appears at the end of the search bar. You are then able to scroll through a number of preselected images. For example, you can select the website’s logo, a screenshot of the page or one of the images that appear on the page.